# Xcode 5 doesn't let me export unsigned cocoa application

Tags: macos, cocoa, xcode5, codesign

When I try to export a cocoa application in XCode 5 GM (which probably isn't anymore under NDA, if it is it will be off tomorrow) doesn't give me the option to export an unsigned application as it did in xcode 4.6
<
When I pick up an archive and select export as application as shown here:

[image: export as application]

In the next screen I have no chances to save it as an unsigned application, as I did before.

Xcode 5:

[image: xcode5]

Xcode 4:

[image: xcode4]

Any Idea on why? is this a bug?

Thanks

Comment: I'm curious, have you tried reproducing this in the Xcode 6 betas? If it's still there it would be worth filing a bug.

Answer (score 19):

This seems like a bug. Even with the target signing settings set to "None" as below, I get the same prompt as you do.

[image]

### A work around

Select `Export as Archive` instead. Once you save the archive, you can control (or right)-click on the archive in Finder and select `Show Package Contents`. The .app will be located under Products/Applications in side of the package.

An alternative would be to control (or right)-click on the build in the Xcode organizer and select `Show in Finder` to show the archive without exporting it. From there you can browse the archive as above to find the .app.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I was already using the workaround to find the .app in Products, btw you don't need to mess with finder as you can find the app in the xcode navigator panel, under products. Thanks anyway!