# Cannot export unsigned IPA from Xcode 5

Tags: ios, xcode5, codesign

Under Xcode 4 I was able to export an unsigned IPA in order to send that to clients with Enterprise accounts for resigning. With the upgrade to Xcode 5 this option has been removed. I found a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18816225/xcode-5-doesnt-let-me-export-unsigned-cocoa-application) that found a work around for Cocoa apps, but this won't work for iOS apps as it yields a .app file.

Does anyone know how an unsigned IPA can be generated from Xcode 5, *or* know of another way to give something to my client for resigning that doesn't involve trading certificates or the project itself?

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: @Kreiri I've updated the question to make it more clear what I'm asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had the exact same problem.  We used this process for a year to deliver an unsigned IPA to our client, who would then sign it when their Enterprise Profile to release it to all their employee's.  The work around turned out to be pretty straight forward.  We just signed the IPA with one of our Distribution Profiles, and the customer, in turn, was able to take that signed IPA and resign it with their Enterprise Distribution Profile.  It turns out, having the "Don't Resign" option in the drop down was not needed.

Comment: What do you do about the bundle identifier?

Comment: We don't need to change it in our case, we build it with the correct bundle identifier that the client needs from the start.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this in your `*.xcodeproj` directory:

```
xcodebuild -project YOUR_PROJECT.xcodeproj -exportArchive -exportFormat ipa -archivePath $(pwd)/YOUR_PROJECT.xcarchive -exportPath $(pwd)/YOUR_PROJECT.ipa CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO -alltargets -configuration Release
```

You can create `.xcarchive` by running:

```
xcodebuild -scheme YOUR_PROJECT_SCHEME archive CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO -archivePath $(pwd)/YOUR_PROJECT.xcarchive
```

You can create `scheme` by using [xcodeproj](http://rubydoc.info/gems/xcodeproj) and this ruby`(.rb)` script:

```
require 'xcodeproj'
xcproj = Xcodeproj::Project.open("YOUR_PROJECT.xcodeproj")
xcproj.recreate_user_schemes
xcproj.save
```

You can install `xcodeproj` by running:

```
sudo gem install xcodeproj :)
```